# QNX RTOS on BeagleBone Green

Tags: rtos, qnx

Hi) As far as I know embedded linux bsp for BeagleBone Green is not real time and we need RTOS to implement our software, so we decided to use QNX. We have experiance with buildroot and poky. What are the ways to use RTOS QNX on BeagleBone Green? Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pre-emptive patches for the standart linux kernels or any other rt-kernels like RTAI / Xenomai.

If you want to use QNX with the beaglebone, firstly you should have QNX SDP(Software Development Platform). Then you need download Beaglebone BSP from the QNX page. I worked with Beaglebone white and Beaglebone black with QNX. In my opinion, beaglebone green could work with this BSP.

```
https://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/TiAm335Beaglebone
```

Also there is one more point with QNX, if you want to use the graphics driver with Beaglebone, you should contact with the sales. It was like that 3 years ago may be for now, they publish the graphics drivers also.

Comment: Thank you for the info!)  appreciate your help!)